# Android: AudioManager for audio, is there a equivalent for Video

Tags: android, video, controls, android-audiomanager

For android, I've researched for controlling Audio using AudioManager. Will there be one for video which I can control the video player to play/stop/pause.

Comment: There is a `MediaPlayer` and `VideoView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `AudioManager` isn't really to control audio playback, but to control such properties as volume, audio mode, and so on. If there is a media player in the background, that doesn't really mean that you control it, you can only send certain requests to the `AudioManager` which cause the system either to take some actions regarding the audio, or to send some events, which the audio player may respond to. So you don't have direct control over the other application.

Likewise, there is no system service which will make the video pause. The best equivalent of `AudioManager` you have which controls what is shown on the screen is `WindowManager`, but I think it's obvious that it can't be used to make a video player pause.

Your best bet for controlling an external video player would be to look up its intents, it may have some ways to control the playback from outside. This, of course, will be application specific.

Comment: I am not mean direct control. I mean just to handle the pause/stop/play. At the moment I can pause a youtube video or a video I played on a media player using AudioManager.

Comment: Pause/stop/play is precisely what direct control means. What do you currently call on the audio manager, by the way?

Comment: AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);

        KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);

Comment: @Simon Right, so these are universal media buttons, they are not audio specific. Like I said, you don't have direct control over the other apps, you can only make the system send a request to them to cease playback, which is what you already do. If they don't already do the action you need, then there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I see at the moment that is what i want it to do... what is the different between MediaSessionManager in API 21 and things below that like RemoteControlClient.

Comment: @Simon If I'm not mistaken, they allow audio players to publish some information regarding the state they are in. However, I doubt these APIs will help you control playback.

Comment: Is ok.. Thanks for answering my problem

Comment: @Simon Glad to help. Please upvote/accept if you find my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API like VideoManager

You can handle videos through Primary API [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) and also see this useful [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888) of multiple ways to handle videos